# How does one close a Meta Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, vote-to-close

I checked the FAQ, and did not see a topic covering Meta Stack Overflow.

Googling found a hit mentioning a "delete" button, but its not available for me.

How does one close the account? It seems all my questions were migrated from elsewhere. Please don't take offense, but I never really asked for or wanted the account.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account ?